# Render a PlantUML diagram in an asciidoc readme in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, asciidoc, plantuml

I'm trying to put my diagrams in the readme and from looking at the [gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/integration/plantuml.html) it seems like it can be done by default. However, GitLab doesn't render my diagrams.

I used the same method as in the example in the docs and also tried this:

```
[plantuml, format="png", id="UseCase", width="200px"]
plantuml:Diagrams/UseCase.puml[]
```

This renders just `plantuml::Diagrams/BookHubUseCase.puml[]`.

The GitLab example with the code block renders just the code block.

How can I render these diagrams in my README? I want to avoid having to have pngs in the repo and setting up CI to render them on change.

Comment: What is plantuml::Diagrams/UseCase.puml[]? I suppose it's expecting just plantuml raw code, not a path to a file. Also yo missed `---`.

Comment: @MuravyevMaxim It's a link to the file, should work like that, shouldn't it? Anyways, the part with the `----` code block is what's in the example and I have tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/integration/plantuml.html), `PlantUML` integration is enabled by default only for [SaaS GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/subscriptions/gitlab_com/):

> With the PlantUML integration, you can create diagrams in snippets,
> wikis, and repositories. This integration is enabled on GitLab.com for
> all SaaS users and does not require any additional configuration.

So if you are using SaaS solution - you can create [support request](https://support.gitlab.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=334447) in this situation.

If you are using [self-managed](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/subscriptions/self_managed/) GitLab instance - your administrators have to [configure](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/integration/plantuml.html#configure-your-plantuml-server) `PlantUML` server first and then [enable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/integration/plantuml.html#enable-plantuml-integration) the integration. You can try to check if `PlantUML` is available by accessing the `https://your.gitlab.com/-/plantuml/` url, but this [may not work](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/integration/plantuml.html#404-error-when-opening-the-plantuml-page-in-the-browser) in all cases. The easiest way will be to clarify with your administrators if `PlantUML` integration is enabled or not.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I didn't realise it's not enabled by default on a self-hosted instance.

Answer (score 1):

To render the PlantUML diagram locally, you can use my Jamal preprocessor that has support for PlantUML natively before 2.5.0 and via Kroki following that version.

That way, you get an adoc file that references a PNG or SVG file during the editing, and it will render properly on any platform.

DISCLAIMER: I wrote Jamal; it is open source, available from Maven central as well as from https://github.com/verhas/jamal

For example, can edit your README.adoc.jam in IntelliJ or AsciidocFX, and the Acsiidoc preprocessor version of Jamal installed will continuously create the SVG or PNG file when needed and save the processed file into README.adoc containing the reference to the image.